# Remove duplicate elements in array

Tags: php

i have search SO but most of the results is similar to [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

i've tried array_unique, but does not work.

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => ball_24.gif
                [1] => ball_8.gif
                [2] => ball_1.gif
                [3] => ball_33.gif
                [4] => ball_43.gif
                [5] => ball_1.gif
                [6] => ball_8.gif
                [7] => ball_24.gif
                [8] => ball_33.gif
                [9] => ball_43.gif
            )

    )
```

Comment: You have an array of arrays. You need to do `array_unique` on the inner array, i.e. `array_unique($array[0])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array[0] = array_unique($array[0]);
```